# how to use media query for height?

Tags: angularjs, html, css

I'm working in web project(Angularjs) and facing one problem. I have given height: 80% and my screen resolution is 1280 x 1024. but when I opened same project in my laptop(Resolution 1386*768) Div get invisible. I have tried following code

```
@media (min-height: 500px){
  #chatViewList 
    {
      overflow-y: auto;
      position: relative;
      height: 80%;
    }
}
```

Please suggest andd help me.

Comment: Could you create a [codepen](https://codepen.io/) or jsfiddle to make test with all of your code easier?

Comment: If possible, please provide working fiddle.

Comment: @AnthonyB thanks for your reply. I tried to create but have resolution issue. didn't get expected output in fiddle.

Comment: In a media query we usually define the tag on wich we are working on. Example body, div, etc.You could write in your CSS on what tag (you div perhaps) you are working on.

Comment: @AbhishekPandey I tried but didn't get expected output

Comment: @Sam that's not easy for test. But test [it](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp), these media query are more precise (they use tag name in CSS selector in media query)

Comment: Can you provide link of your web project?

Answer (score 1):

VH is what you need!
     `height: 100vh;` = `100% of device height`
You can of course use like `80vh` for 80% of the device height. VH means `viewport height`

Answer (score 1):

Is the height of the parent element fixed? If not you can't use a percentage based height (there are some exceptions but they're unlikely to be practical).

I would suggest using the viewport height unit instead. `vh` allows you to specify a height in relation to the viewport window.

```
@media (min-height: 500px) {
    #chatViewList {
        height: 80vh;
        overflow-y: auto;
        position: relative;
    }
}
```

Browser support: http://caniuse.com/#search=vh

Comment: It's highly likely your issue is elsewhere then. That code on it's own will work fine (tested). It could be that you have other styles overriding your element or that you have a parent element acting on it in some way.

Comment: Sorry. let me implement or check it  again then will get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the responsive height of a div when it's part of a parent div that has a defined height.

Or, You can pre-define the height of the div or dynamic specify static values based on various commonly available heights <-- could be an overkill but can work.
Alternatively, try the following links"

- https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-make-div-height-responsive/30438
  OR
- http://www.minimit.com/articles/solutions-tutorials/bootstrap-3-responsive-columns-of-same-height

Answer (score 0):

Its not best practice to create media queries to resolution height. how ever as you asked here I guess you trying to create full screen web page. to make it work set you html tag and body tag height 100%

ex:

```
html, body { 
    min-height: 100%; 
    hight: 100%;
}
```

like this what ever resolution you working on web page hight will remain 100%. then add CSS height as percentage as you wish. And also make sure you set `min-height` and `max-height` to all.

This is a little trick that I am using when creating full screen web pages

Hope this will help

Comment: I'll try and get back to you soon @Tharaka

Answer (score 0):

for calculating the screen height for every screen we can use this formula.

```
height:calc(100% - 200px);
```

which calculate the height and subtracts 200px from it.
we can use any value in place of 200px
example

```
#div1 {

    height:calc(100% - 200px);  

}
```

if the screen size is 1000, Resulting div1 height will be 800